# PHPUnit Stub, I want to replace a function in test

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, stub

So I have this builder that runs a buildClass method which should be public, and it takes a couple of arguments.

In my test I want to remove those arguments completely and add something completely different using the Mock in PHPUnit.

So: from:

```
class ClassBuilder{
  public function buildClass($id, $some, $vars){
    $class = new Class($id, $some, $vars);
    return self::getClass(db_Class, $class);
  }
}
```

So you might get my idea here, I want to make a mock so it does the return function there.

```
$myClassStub->getMock("ClassBuilder");
$myClassStub->->expects($this->any())
    ->method("buildClass")
    ->with($this->anything(), $this->anything())
    ->will($this->returnCallback("getClass"));
```

But I have no idea how it works. This is how I thought it would be, but I have no clue where to put the arguments at all. Please help me out here, much appriciated.

/Marcus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just leave out the `->with($this->anything(), $this->anything())` exepct if it is there to make sure that you pass at least 2 arguments into that function.

Apart from you that I've understood is that you want to return a different class. In that case I'd suggest doing:

```
$yourClassToReturn = "..."; // create the class here

$myClassStub->getMock("ClassBuilder");
$myClassStub->expects($this->any())
    ->method("buildClass")
    ->with($this->anything(), $this->anything())
    ->will($this->returnValue($yourClassToReturn));
```

Comment: Ok, so $yourClassToReturn is also a mock instance then? So I set that one up the same way. Brilliant. However, the class I want to construct using the builder is done from another class in the ClassBuilder. So bottom line is that I want to run a function in class builder, as this is a private function. Is that possible?

Comment: The point is that when you mock out the ClassBuilder you don't to care anymore about it's private methods as your fake "buildClass" will not interact with them anyways. You just tell it "do exactly this" with no logic what so ever. (If that makes sense and i understood you right? :) )

Comment: Well my intentions is to mock parts of the functionality, rather and test other parts.

Comment: @edorian is `->->` a typo that should be removed?